# Is everyone seeing how often I click on my own questions?

Tags: discussion

Is everyone else, other standard users of the site I mean, seeing how often I click on my own questions? Do those views show up, on the view count, for other (standard users of the site)?

These views don't show up for me.

I am only clicking again (on my questions( to make sure the question is properly phrased...

Comment: This is unclear to me. The system is built to not increase view-count if the new page load is from the (presumed) same user. This is designed to compensate for a certain amount of time to have passed. If you click *any* post, views go up by 1, if you click it again in 5min, it stays, if you let a day pass (don't know the numbers) it gets views+1. However, the meta-data you generate with actions while logged in is recorded by SE (& not publicly accessible AFAIK). So, what is it: (public) views increment, or what exactly *you* did? Please [edit] for clarification?